Units in Fluid Mechanics Energy equation not agreeing
I'm gearing up to simulate some 2D Euler equations. I want the fluid to be compressible, so I need slightly more general equations than given by NASA and most of the forms on Wikipedia. Instead, I'm basically doing the Navier-Stokes equations without viscosity.
I've been going through Tong's lecture notes 1 and 2 from Cambridge today and gotten a good understanding of where the conservation of mass and momentum equations come from. Wikipedia is also helpful for those. I agree with NASA's slide that $\rho(\vec{x}, t)$ needs to end up inside the derivative expressions, rather than the $\rho \frac{D\vec{u}}{Dt}$ we usually see listed, which is the simplified form.
But I'm having trouble on the conservation of energy equation. The units don't even seem to work out. Whereas in the other equations I can say "Okay, that's a time derivative of momentum times velocity, so the units are $\frac{mass}{length^2 \ time^2}$ in the first term, and then spatial derivative of momentum times velocity squared (same units), and then on the other side I have a spatial derivative of pressure, which is force per area (same units)", I can't make the units in the energy equation agree. I also can't find a derivation of this more general form, because most derivations of an energy equation make simplifications, like assuming non-compressibility, early in the process.
If $E$ is total energy and has units of $\frac{mass \ length^2}{time^2}$, so the time derivative has units of power $\frac{mass \ length^2}{time^3}$, then how can the left side equal the right, which must have units of $\frac{pressure \ velocity}{length} = \frac{mass}{length \ time^3}$? What am I missing? I want to see a derivation that clears this up.

I didn't look at any of your links, but intuition from teaching + looking at your units makes me think what you're calling the right hand side has units of energy density, which has units of energy divided by volume.

Yes, I think you're right. The only way this works is if E doesn't have the units implied by "total energy". This resource has the equations in a little more of the form I want them, and little $e$ has units $\frac{length^2}{time^2}$. I'd still like to see a proper derivation.

You said $dE/dt$ has units of $ML^2/T^3$. If instead of $E$ you wanted $\rho=E/V$ (energy density), you should divide your answer by $L^3$, which gives $M/L T^3$, which is what you wanted.

There's a proper physicist-level discussion of the Navier-Stokes equations here, among other places. If you don't like the derivation in those notes, the notes also has a set of recommended references.

This is helpful too https://web.stanford.edu/class/cme306/Homework/hwk8_solution.pdf
